# How to handle the case when click_action was sent to the previous version of the app where intent-filter was not added yet?

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Could you help me to solve the problem?

The task is develop push notification that will open particular Activity by users tap.

I've added intent-filter and tried to send the push message with the click_action field, and everything works like a charm.

The problem is with the previous version of the application where Intent-filter was not added yet. If user tap on the push message (in the case of previous app version), nothing happens.

What is better to do in this case? How to handle such situations?

**Edit:**

So the question is, how can we have default behavior (opening the app on the last screen) in the case of specific screen mentioned in click_action field and lacking of necessary intent-filter? This relevant for situation when the user has previous version of the app without necessary intent-filter in the manifest file.

Comment: Have the users update to a newer version of your app to see the "*new features*".

Comment: I am not pushing users to install the new version of my app, and I assume that some part of users will use the previous version. So the question is, how can we have default behaviour (opening the app on the last screen) in the case of lacking necessary intent-filter

Comment: @Val I think that comment implied that if the new feature is not available on previous versions, you'd rather not want the intent-filter to be triggered on these previous versions.
So in your case, if the new feature is to open the last screen, there is no reason to make it work if the code to open the last screen is not on the previous version of your app.

Answer (score -1):

To perform some action on push-notification click we need to write code for that to perform such action. In your case you want to perform some action on your old live application, In this can you can't do anything.

To perform some action you can call this method on push notification received

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityName.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{01})
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notification);
    else
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notification);


    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is clear. But how to have backward compatibility with the previous versions of the app, this is the question. For example in the case of the previous version I want the app just to be opened like usually happens if user clicks on the usual push notification.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but looks like you provided the code which shows local notification, correct? But I am talking about notification that came from FireBase. And the main question is, how can we launch default android.intent.action.MAIN intent in the case if there is no specific intent in the manifest file of the previous version of the app. So, you think that it is not possible, right?